# Single Digit Captcha Match, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, captcha

I run a PTC website advertising websites for people. And i'm needing an easy to to lower or completely prevent bot usage.

After the advertisement counter is done counting down i would like a captcha to load.

But i don't want a captcha that you have to enter anything. Just a single mouse click.

If the captcha can be done in javascript that would be really great.

I'm looking for something sort of like this:

Counter:0 Select Matching Number: 7 [1] [0] [7] [2]

The user would have to click on the number in the box that matches the number.

Digits would be within 1-9.

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be great, too. Good luck.

Comment: I've tried looking around for the captcha that i'm wanting but only source i could find is for the types that you have to enter in the code.. which is not what i'm looking for... I just want a simple way even just matching image names would possibly suffice?

Comment: Another thing to think about: The captcha has 4 numbers with the range of `0-9`. One is correct. That gives only for different options. If a bot tried the first one on a form (presuming the form only allows one try), they would only have to try the first number four times before they would get through...

Comment: If the fail to select the right option, then they will fail to receive the credit for viewing the ad. So failing is ok, and i could track how many fails, etc.

Comment: something like: http://www.confidenttechnologies.com/products/confident-captcha

Comment: this would of been ok, but the captcha itself has to be rather small, and in-line.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: Sorry, I meant ***10*** times, not *4*.

Comment: If you can't find something that fits your (pretty specific needs), write it yourself. There isn't a ready-made script for everything.

Comment: `There isn't a ready-made script for everything` - No, there isn't, unless someone writes one :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short of a full captcha you wont stop a determined bot.

A few ideas.

Allow 10 - 15 requests within 10 a minutes period, if it exceeds that, ask for captcha or block completely.  Make sure this is IP based, because cookies/session wont work

Add some javascript to the form so that it cannot be posted without it. Most email collecting spam bots won't run javascript and give up. Generate a random string, store in $_SESSION on page request. Use javascript to add to the form post. if that string doesn't exist match on form post display a captcha.

Or use javascript to contstruct the form itself.

A determined scraper can get around most anything, but you just want to increase the cost of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) script. It's size, number of characters, and characters to choose from are customizable.

**Here is `captcha.php`:**

```
<?php
function generateCaptcha($num_digits, $challenge_num, $size, $chars, $incode = false) {
    if(session_id() == '') session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['captcha'])) unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
    // You *must* type your own random salt here, *DO NOT* use this one.
    $salt = 'H#(*h3^rh@(*E%h$W*WK#vMIv)%(D*(A&*W@A^D6@r4*I%u8tgsc#yejdi$d8dee';
    $message = '';
    if(isset($_POST['hash']) && isset($_POST['code'])) {
        if(!empty($_POST['hash']) && !empty($_POST['code']) && !empty($_POST['correct_index'])) {
            if(md5($_POST['hash'] . $_POST['code'] . $salt) == $_POST['correct_index']) {
                $message = '<p>Correct!</p>';
            } else {
                $message = 'Incorrect code. Please try again.';
            }
        }
    }
    $code = '';
    if($incode == false) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_digits; $i++) {
            $digit = substr($chars, floor(mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)), 1);
            while(strpos($code, "$digit") !== false) {
                $digit = substr($chars, floor(mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)), 1);
            }
            $code .= $digit;
        }
    } else {
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_digits; $i++) {
            $digit = substr($incode, floor(mt_rand(0, strlen($incode) - 1)), 1);
            while(strpos($code, "$digit") !== false) {
                $digit = substr($incode, floor(mt_rand(0, strlen($incode) - 1)), 1);
            }
            $code .= $digit;
        }
    }
    $parts = str_split($code);
    $width = $num_digits * $size;
    $height = $size * 2;
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $background = imagecolorallocate($image, floor(mt_rand(96, 255)), floor(mt_rand(96, 255)), floor(mt_rand(96, 255)));
    imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);
    $num_spots = floor(mt_rand($size * 2, $size * 15));
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_spots; $i++) {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, floor(mt_rand(30, 255)), floor(mt_rand(30, 255)), floor(mt_rand(30, 255)));
        $x = floor(mt_rand(0, $width));
        $y = floor(mt_rand(0, $height));
        $ellipse_width = floor(mt_rand(0, $size / 2));
        $ellipse_height = floor(mt_rand(0, $size / 2));
        imagefilledellipse($image, $x, $y, $ellipse_width, $ellipse_height, $color);
        $x1 = floor(mt_rand(0, $width));
        $y1 = floor(mt_rand(0, $height));
        $x2 = floor(mt_rand(0, $width));
        $y2 = floor(mt_rand(0, $height));
        imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color);
    }
    $num_dots = floor(mt_rand($size * 50, $size * 80));
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_dots; $i++) {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, floor(mt_rand(30, 255)), floor(mt_rand(30, 255)), floor(mt_rand(30, 255)));
        $x = floor(mt_rand(0, $width));
        $y = floor(mt_rand(0, $height));
        imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, $color);
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, floor(mt_rand(0, 150)), floor(mt_rand(0, 150)), floor(mt_rand(0, 150)));
        $x = floor(mt_rand($size * 0.9, $size * 1.1));
        $y = floor(mt_rand($size, $size * 2));
        imagettftext($image, $size, floor(mt_rand(-10, 10)), $i * $x, $y, $color, 'Justus-Bold.ttf', $parts[$i]);
        imagettftext($image, $size, floor(mt_rand(-10, 10)), $i * $x + floor(mt_rand(1, 7)), $y, $color, 'Justus-Bold.ttf', $parts[$i]);
        imagettftext($image, $size, floor(mt_rand(-10, 10)), $i * $x + floor(mt_rand(1, 7)), $y, $color, 'Justus-Bold.ttf', $parts[$i]);
        imagettftext($image, $size, floor(mt_rand(-10, 10)), $i * $x + floor(mt_rand(1, 7)), $y, $color, 'Justus-Bold.ttf', $parts[$i]);
    }
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $filename = md5(time() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . mt_rand(0, 1000)) . '.png';
    imagepng($image, $filename);
    imagedestroy($image);
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
    $imgsize = getimagesize($filename);
    unlink($filename);
    $captcha = 'data:' . $imgsize['mime'] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($file);
    $challenge = array('captcha' => '', 'code' => null, 'size' => 0, 'digits' => 0);
    if($incode == false) {
        $challenge = generateCaptcha($challenge_num, 0, $size, $chars, $code);
    }
    $hash = md5($challenge['code'] . $salt);
    $correct_index = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($challenge['code']); $i++) {
        $correct_index[] = strpos($code, substr($challenge['code'], $i, 1));
    }
    $result = array(
        'captcha' => $captcha,
        'challenge' => array($challenge['captcha'], $challenge['size'], $challenge['digits']),
        'size' => array($imgsize[0], $imgsize[1]),
        'hash' => $hash,
        'code' => $code,
        'message' => $message,
        'width' => $size,
        'digits' => $num_digits,
        'correct_index' => md5($hash . implode('', $correct_index) . $salt)
    );
    return $result;
}
?>
```

**...and here is `captcha.html`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
<?php
include 'captcha.php';
$captcha = generateCaptcha(4, 2, 100, '0123456789');
?>
-->
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Click-captcha test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
#challenge, #captcha-img {
    margin: 10px
}
#captcha-img {
    overflow: hidden
}
.captcha-digit {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: <?php echo $captcha['width']; ?>px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer
}
.captcha-digit-selected {
    background: #ccc;
    opacity: .75;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(StartColorStr='#f2cccccc', EndColorStr='#f2cccccc')
}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var captchaLinks = [];
var digits = [];
var num_digits = <?php echo $captcha['challenge'][2]; ?> - 1;
addEvent(window, 'load', init);
function init() {
    captchaLinks = ['<?php
$digits = array();
for($i = 'digit0'; $i < 'digit' . $captcha['digits']; $i++) {
    $digits[] = $i;
}
echo implode("', '", $digits);
?>'];
    for(var i = 0; i < captchaLinks.length; i++) {
    //for(var link in captchaLinks) {
        addEvent(document.getElementById(captchaLinks[i]), 'click', newCaptchaDigit);
    }
}
function newCaptchaDigit(e) {
        if(e.target.className == 'captcha-digit captcha-digit-selected') {
            digits.splice(digits.indexOf(e.target.id.substr(-1, 1)), 1);
            e.target.className = 'captcha-digit';
        } else if(digits.length <= num_digits) {
            digits.splice(num_digits, digits.length - num_digits, e.target.id.substr(-1, 1));
            e.target.className = 'captcha-digit captcha-digit-selected';
        }
        document.getElementById('code').value = digits.join('');
}
function addEvent(elem, event, handler) {
    if(elem !== null & typeof elem !== 'undefined') {
        if(elem.addEventListener) {
            elem.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        } else if(elem.attachEvent) {
            elem.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
        } else if(elem['on' + event]) {
            elem['on' + event] = handler;
        }
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
            <div id="captcha">
                <div><?php echo $captcha['message']; ?></div>
                <div>Click the following number sequence:
                    <div id="challenge" style="width: <?php echo $captcha['challenge'][1][0]; ?>px; height: <?php echo $captcha['challenge'][1][1]; ?>px; background-image: url('<?php echo $captcha['challenge'][0]; ?>')"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="captcha-img" style="width: <?php echo $captcha['size'][0]; ?>px; height: <?php echo $captcha['size'][1]; ?>px; background-image: url('<?php echo $captcha['captcha']; ?>')">
<?php for($i = 'digit0'; $i < 'digit' . $captcha['digits']; $i++) { ?>
                    <a class="captcha-digit" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="<?php echo $captcha['hash']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="correct_index" value="<?php echo $captcha['correct_index']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="code" id="code" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully you will able to see what is going on, but I will explain it here. :-)

The function is called `generateCaptcha`, and it accepts the parameters `$num_digits, $challenge_num, $size, $chars, $incode = false`.

---

- `$num_digits`: number of characters to put in the CAPTCHA
- `$challenge_num`: number of characters to put into the challenge
- `$size`: size of the CAPTCHA
- `$chars`: what characters to include (e.g. for numbers: `'0123456789'`)
- `$incode`: this is just so the script can tell if it has been called by itself to generate the challenge or not. **Don't set it.**

So to create a CAPTCHA image with 4 characters, a 1 character challenge (like your question), size 30, and only with digits, use this code:

```
<?php
include 'captcha.php';
$captcha = generateCaptcha(4, 1, 30, '0123456789');
?>
```

Then the variable `$captcha` will end up something like this:

```
array(9) {
  ["captcha"]=>
  string(118058) "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...kSuQmCC"
  ["challenge"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(76266) "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...kJggg=="
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(200)
      [1]=>
      int(200)
    }
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
  ["size"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(400)
    [1]=>
    int(200)
  }
  ["hash"]=>
  string(32) "81bc501400b8da366e70b26007cb2323"
  ["code"]=>
  string(4) "4817"
  ["message"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["width"]=>
  int(100)
  ["digits"]=>
  int(4)
  ["correct_index"]=>
  string(32) "17ae615be69c757505dc7f69fce2afb1"
}
```

If you need any more information, please ask in a comment.

Comment: I just noticed that it used to be working fine, but now half of the time it doesn't recognize when a CAPTCHA has been submitted. I will have to look into that...

Comment: Another couple of notes: **(1):** I found a way to use it without sessions, so you can remove all session code from the top of the script. I will remove that in an edit when I fix the previously mentioned bug. **(2):** *Remember to create you own salt, as per the comment in the code.* This is for security.